# how to do index time filed boost in solr using solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr

I am new to `solr`. Currently we are using `solr 4.8.0`. We have already done indexing, created fields, field types. Now I want to boost some of the fields using index time boosting. Does this have to be done in `solrconfig.xml`? What are the tags and syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Index time boosts are applied for each field when the document is submitted to the index. You can either apply the boost to hits in a specific field or for the document as the whole (which would apply the same boost to all fields).

[Example from the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22):

```
<add>
  <doc boost="2.5">
    <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
    <field name="office" boost="2.0">Bridgewater</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: is this to be added in solrconfig.xml?Im not passing any values through solr.I want to boost a particular field eg employeeid ^ 20.0.where and how can i add it using index time field boosting

Comment: We have not created documents physically we are creating documents using mysql query.so the above code will not work in my case.now how can i boost fields?

Comment: You cannot boost individual fields using DataImportHandler as far as I know. You'll have to apply the boost at query time in that case.